# Cannot run certain queries in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

**The Problem**

I have been encountering a problem with MSAccess 2007, with a 2003 format database.

When I try to run the query (for example a select query), I get the message "**The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file "query name". It is already opened exclusively by another user or you need permission to view and write its data**".

In addition, I cannot view the query in design view, only in SQL view. This only happens for certain queries, which I was previously able to design and change with no issues.

**What I have tried**

I have tried Repairing and Compacting, and that does not fix the problem. The only way I have been able to fix so far is by importing all the objects into a new database, which has resolved the problem for a while, then a few days later the same issue happens again.

Comment: All service packs are installed? Unfortunately, Access is "well known" for breaking its databases every now and then...

Comment: I get Microsoft Office Access (12.0.4518.1014) MSO (12.0.6662.5000) in Help About

Comment: Then you are [definitely missing some service packs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116).

Comment: OK cheers, that is one avenue to explore at least.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434296/share-a-mdb-file-over-network-for-many-computers-cant-edit-the-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a multi-user environment, and the back end database is on a share drive, this will happen when someone else opens the back end database directly from the shared drive instead of using the local front end database.  If the back end database is opened directly from the shared drive, other users will be unable to use the front end database due to locking issues.

Comment: Yes, this was more or less the problem. In actual fact I discovered it occurred only on queries that referenced a linked table, if that linked table happened to be open in another database then the issue ocurred. When they closed it it went away.